# embed AWS S3 video using video.js in html site

Tags: video.js

I am in new territory for me here. I am trying to embed AWS S3 hosted video into a html website authored with Netobjects Fusion.

I tried putting in the code from the getting started page and successfully got my website to play the video.js promo video, however, when I try to alter that to play my videos I get an invalid file path error. Below is the altered code. Can anyone direct me as to what I am missing or messing up? Do I need to define the video id somewhere else? Also, I am not sure what to do with the data-setup='{"example_option":true}'> line. Thanks.

```
<link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>


<video id="6915MLD" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
  controls preload="auto" width="640" height="480"
  poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/premiervideotours/PVTx320.jpg"
  data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
 <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/premiervideotours/PVT-6915MLD2015b2b.mpg" type='video/mp4' />
 <source src="https://https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/premiervideotours/PVT-6915MLD2015b2b.webm" type='video/webm' />
</video>
```

Comment: One correction I made - the first path had "mpg" in it. It should have been "mp4" but after correcting that I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Even after correcting your URLs to the below, I get access denied when visiting them in a browser.

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/premiervideotours/PVT-6915MLD2015b2b.mp4 (mpg to mp4)
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/premiervideotours/PVT-6915MLD2015b2b.webm (removed duplicate https://)

S3 will respond with access denied not only when the permissions of the file don't allow access, but also when the file is not found. So check both whether the files are in the location the URLs point to, and whether they are 'public'.

Re `data-setup='{"example_option":true}` - there are a couple of options to set up video.js after including the script and css. One is to include a `data-setup` attribute. The value of the attribute is a json string which can include setup options or be empty, e.g. `data-setup='{}`. The "example_option" is just that, an example of how it would look if you need to pass setup options.